# Self-Signed Certificate and IIS 6.0, How to generate a Client Certificate

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-6, ssl-certificate

I am looking at generating a self-signed certificate, and only allow users who has client certificate installed on my web server. I am using IIS 6.0 with selfSSL to generate my .pfx web server certificate.
i was looking at this atricle http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=11&page=3 and it mentions about installing Client Certificate on Client Machine. How do i generate a Client certificate? do i use SelfSSL as well?
if i use SelfSSL do i Use

```
selfssl.exe /N:CN=ClientName /K:1024 /V:7 /S:1 /P:443
```

OR DO i install the same certificate installed on web server?

Comment: Cross posted http://superuser.com/questions/308204/self-signed-certificate-and-iis-6-0-how-to-generate-a-client-certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate client certificates using the Microsoft makecert utility (this utility is available in the Windows SDK):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(v=vs.80).aspx

For example, the following command line will create a self-signed certificate, with an exportable private exchange key, and place it in the client's personal certificate store.

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=Recipient1" -sky exchange -ss my
```

In the event that the server does not trust this certificate, you will also have to add it to the server's Root Certificate Store, since it is self signed.

Comment: can i use makecert also from createing certificate for web server?

Comment: AFAIK, you could use makecert to create the web server certificate but I recommend selfssl because it does all the work for you -- it generates an SSL certificate and adds it to your website.  Using makecert requires more steps.